# PICKit3 Connection Fails

Tags: pic, pickit

I am an absolute beginner to PIC microcontrollers. I am using PICKit3 to program a PIC18F4550 and MPLABX-IDE / MPLAB IPE version 5.20.

The problem I'm not able to solve is that the connection to pickit3 always fails and I don't know why. I looked at countless similar questions but none could solve the problem. Here are the complete details:

PICKit3 Programmer

PIC ICD2 PICKit2 PICKIT3 Universal Programming Adapter Programmer Board

MPLAB-X IDE / MPLAB IPE v5.20

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

The first problem I was getting was that my USB port was supplying 4.750000 volts instead of the required 5V. So I used an Arduino as an external power source.

Connection diagram:

[image]

And the MPLAB IPE Screen:

[image]

Comment: Did you read the manual? Your diagram lacks ground connection between Pickit and target. And the supply voltage connection too. And there is no pull-up resistor on the MCLR.

Comment: Try sticking the chip in a breadboard and connecting the programmer to the right pins with jumpers. Make sure the programmer is configured to supply power to VDD.

Comment: I'm not sure if you need the MCLR pullup for programming, but you could try adding it.

Comment: If that doesn't work double check your connections, and then try a new chip. It's fairly easy to burn them out with you connect the programmer incorrectly.

Comment: I checked the connections, they're correct. I will get a new chip and try on it.

Comment: I got a new microcontroller chip, but still the same error

Comment: If you use an external power supply, you had to switch off the power suplly from the PICKit

Comment: yes, I did that too